# windows 7 getting Error on sending data to socket

Tags: sockets, windows-7

I have an older tcp/ip telnet client that is no longer supported.  It has always worked fine on windows XP.  I have "upgraded" to windows 7 and it no longer will do a file transfer.  When I try, it times out and gives me Error on sending data to socket - Socket 1202 - machine xx.xx.xx.xx status = -2107.  I am vpn'd in when I do this on both machines using the standard windows vpn connection for each, but I only get this error on the Windows 7 Machine.  Any suggestions on how to resolve this?  Thanks in advance for any help.